# Sonar PDF report generated on Sonar dashboard but is not coming in email

Tags: sonarqube

I have configured my sonar project view to receive a sonar PDF report however i am still not getting the same on email. Below are the steps I performed:

1. I have created a view where I have included my 6 projects. I gave
   execute permission on view not on individual project.
2. I have set Executive Report option to come daily and provided email
   id's to receive the pdf
3. I have set the Subscribe button which says "You are receiving PDF
   reports by email every day."

Please suggest what is missing. Also the report doesn't include much details about the sonar code analysis. Is it possible to include below parameters:

- Test Coverage
- Unresolved Issues

I am not getting much help from Vendor on same.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You are talking about the feature provided by the commercial Governance product (https://redirect.sonarsource.com/plugins/governance.html). I really doubt that you tried to get help from the vendor (SonarSource), the support/sales team always answer questions related to that product when someone is evaluating the product using a trial license. Disclaimer: I'm part of the company.